# Jenkins windows slave lose connection continuously with error: ClosedChannelException

Tags: java, jenkins, remote-access, jnlp, jenkins-agent

Jenkins 2.107.2

Master: Windows Server 2008R2, java version "1.8.0_171" 
Slave: Windows Server 2016, java version "1.8.0_161" on master

I already tried:

1. turn off firewall
2. change 'Power Options': Turn off the display: Never
3. Jenkins: TCP port for JNLP agents: tried both fixed and Random, with Agent protocols, only `Java Web Start Agent Protocol/4 (TLS encryption)` selected.

Any other things I can try or troubleshoot?

Thank you so much for your help!

Error on the slave node page on the master Jenkins:

```
Connection was broken

java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.ChannelApplicationLayer.onReadClosed(ChannelApplicationLayer.java:208)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.ApplicationLayer.onRecvClosed(ApplicationLayer.java:222)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.ProtocolStack$Ptr.onRecvClosed(ProtocolStack.java:832)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.FilterLayer.onRecvClosed(FilterLayer.java:287)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.SSLEngineFilterLayer.onRecvClosed(SSLEngineFilterLayer.java:181)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.SSLEngineFilterLayer.switchToNoSecure(SSLEngineFilterLayer.java:283)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.SSLEngineFilterLayer.processWrite(SSLEngineFilterLayer.java:503)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.SSLEngineFilterLayer.processQueuedWrites(SSLEngineFilterLayer.java:248)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.SSLEngineFilterLayer.doSend(SSLEngineFilterLayer.java:200)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.SSLEngineFilterLayer.doCloseSend(SSLEngineFilterLayer.java:213)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.ProtocolStack$Ptr.doCloseSend(ProtocolStack.java:800)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.ApplicationLayer.doCloseWrite(ApplicationLayer.java:173)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.ChannelApplicationLayer$ByteBufferCommandTransport.closeWrite(ChannelApplicationLayer.java:313)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.close(Channel.java:1446)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.close(Channel.java:1399)
    at jenkins.slaves.DefaultJnlpSlaveReceiver.afterChannel(DefaultJnlpSlaveReceiver.java:173)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpConnectionState$4.invoke(JnlpConnectionState.java:421)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpConnectionState.fire(JnlpConnectionState.java:312)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpConnectionState.fireAfterChannel(JnlpConnectionState.java:418)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpProtocol4Handler$Handler$1.run(JnlpProtocol4Handler.java:334)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

slave log:

```
May 03, 2018 5:46:35 PM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpAgentEndpointResolver resolve
INFO: Remoting server accepts the following protocols: [JNLP4-connect, Ping]
May 03, 2018 5:47:12 PM hudson.remoting.JarCacheSupport$DownloadRunnable run
WARNING: Failed to resolve a jar c7fd87b9bf7e59d00b1b183cf4aecbfc
java.io.IOException: Failed to write to C:\Users\fazzt\Documents\jenkins\remoting\jarCache\C7\FD87B9BF7E59D00B1B183CF4AECBFC.jar
    at hudson.remoting.FileSystemJarCache.retrieve(FileSystemJarCache.java:150)
    at hudson.remoting.JarCacheSupport$DownloadRunnable.run(JarCacheSupport.java:110)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.AtmostOneThreadExecutor$Worker.run(AtmostOneThreadExecutor.java:112)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Backing channel 'JNLP4-connect connection to QASYSTEM/10.7.208.204:49363' is disconnected.
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler.channelOrFail(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:209)
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:278)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy3.writeJarTo(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.FileSystemJarCache.retrieve(FileSystemJarCache.java:115)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.NetworkLayer.onRecvClosed(NetworkLayer.java:154)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.BIONetworkLayer.access$1500(BIONetworkLayer.java:48)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.BIONetworkLayer$Reader.run(BIONetworkLayer.java:247)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine$1$1.run(Engine.java:94)
    ... 1 more
```

master log:

```
WARNING: Making SlaveNode1 offline because it’s not responding
May 07, 2018 5:59:21 AM jenkins.slaves.DefaultJnlpSlaveReceiver channelClosed
WARNING: Computer.threadPoolForRemoting [#1201] for SlaveNode1 terminated
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.ChannelApplicationLayer.onReadClosed(ChannelApplicationLayer.java:208)
at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.ApplicationLayer.onRecvClosed(ApplicationLayer.java:222)
at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.ProtocolStack$Ptr.onRecvClosed(ProtocolStack.java:832)
at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.FilterLayer.onRecvClosed(FilterLayer.java:287)
at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.SSLEngineFilterLayer.onRecvClosed(SSLEngineFilterLayer.java:181)
at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.SSLEngineFilterLayer.switchToNoSecure(SSLEngineFilterLayer.java:283)
at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.SSLEngineFilterLayer.processWrite(SSLEngineFilterLayer.java:503)
at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.SSLEngineFilterLayer.processQueuedWrites(SSLEngineFilterLayer.java:248)
at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.SSLEngineFilterLayer.doSend(SSLEngineFilterLayer.java:200)
at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.SSLEngineFilterLayer.doCloseSend(SSLEngineFilterLayer.java:213)
at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.ProtocolStack$Ptr.doCloseSend(ProtocolStack.java:800)
at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.ApplicationLayer.doCloseWrite(ApplicationLayer.java:173)
at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.ChannelApplicationLayer$ByteBufferCommandTransport.closeWrite(ChannelApplicationLayer.java:313)
at hudson.remoting.Channel.close(Channel.java:1446)
at hudson.remoting.Channel.close(Channel.java:1399)
at jenkins.slaves.DefaultJnlpSlaveReceiver.afterChannel(DefaultJnlpSlaveReceiver.java:173)
at org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpConnectionState$4.invoke(JnlpConnectionState.java:421)
at org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpConnectionState.fire(JnlpConnectionState.java:312)
at org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpConnectionState.fireAfterChannel(JnlpConnectionState.java:418)
at org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpProtocol4Handler$Handler$1.run(JnlpProtocol4Handler.java:334)
at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: You have posted the slave log - what about the master log?